# Conditional expectation on the space of bounded linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

In the paper from the link http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0139.pdf the author uses a diagonal conditional expectation. We take a seperable Hilbert space $H$ and fix an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

The diagonal conditional expectation is the idempotent map $E \colon \mathbf{B}(H) \rightarrow D$ which erases the off-diagonal entries,

where $D$ is the set made of diagonal elements of $\mathbf{B}(H)$ (that is, $x$ is a diagonal element of $\mathbf{B}(H)$ if $P_{\{e_i\}}xP_{\{e_j\}}= 0$, whenever $i \neq j$, $P_{\{e_k\}}$ is a rank-one projection onto $span\{e_k\}$), and it is a maximal abelian self-adjoint algebra in $\mathbf{B}(H)$ (it is equal to its commutant).

Now let me introduce **bra-ket notation**:

I assume that the inner product in $H$ is linear with respect to the 2nd coordinate.

Let $x \in H$, then

- $\left|x\right> \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow H$ if defined by
  $\left|x\right> \alpha = \alpha x$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$,
- $\left< x \right| \colon H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is
  defined by $\left< x \right| y= \left<x, y \right>$ for all $y \in
     H$.

How does this conditional expectation act on an arbitrary element $T \in \mathbf{B}(H)$, what $E(T)= ?$, can we write it using the bra-ket notation ?

Comment: Your $E(T)$ is not diagonal.

Comment: Yes, I just realised it. Could you tell me how can we write it using the explicit formula?

Comment: Try $\sum \langle e_n |Te_n\rangle |e_n \rangle \langle e_n|$.

Comment: @Michael Your second comment is really an answer. Seriously, please post as an answer...